# Restrict Active Directory user by IP Address or Machine Name

Tags: networking, ip, remote-access, active-directory, restrictions

I am needing to create a Windows Active Directory account for use with a Microsoft Dynamics CRM system to a set of SQL Server 2008 R2 servers.  This user is requiring elevated privileges in my SQL Server environment that I normally do not allow in PROD, but for the purposes of this account - it is necessary (it's being used for Deployments, and to roll things down to lower environments as necessary).

I have tried researching methods of simply locking down an account in AD by either the IP address (for servers) or machine name (for workstations using DHCP), but have not been able to find anything very straight forward on how to do this (I am the DBA - not the SysAdmin, but I'm researching this for them).

Is there a way to simply tell the AD to only allow this user to log in from specific IP addresses AND machine names?

Thank you

Comment: To clarify, you want the user to be able to log into any computer, but you want to only allow them to access SQL if they logged in at a specific IP and/or machine name?

Comment: I want the user to **only** be able to log in from a specific workstation (machine name) to a group of servers via RDP (IP address).  There is the potential that more than one workstation could be used, but I am not 100% certain of that just yet.  The servers are 4 in all, and their IP's are static.

Comment: Techie007 - for further clarity to your question, yes.  I want them to work like everyone else, but their system is the only one that has the designated credentials to both RDP to certain servers, and operate on certain SQL servers with the permissions we are going to grant to this particular AD user (sorry for the late edit, but after looking at your question again - I see what you were driving at, and yes you are correct in your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely after settings on your [Network Policy Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732912.aspx).  You can set constraints and conditions which would reject connections that don't meet your criteria.  Looks like the [Conditions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731220%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) have the ability to set a group of machines that a connection can be received from for a particular user group.

Answer (score -2):

It's in the "Log On To" button on the "Account" Tab.

https://ravingroo.com/267/active-directory-user-workstation-logon-restriction/

Comment: Welcome as a new user, you should note that `Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.` Please take the [Tour] and [answer]